How to load data from GCS to bigquery using the folder name to create tables?
I have a issue here and need your help.
We had data from google analytics (GA4) that was in BigQuery and to reduce our cost we loaded it to Cloud Storage, but now we need to get some of these data back.
The point is that Google Analytics save each day in a table inside the dataset with this pattern: event_YYYYMMDD
We saved the data in GCS with a similar pattern creating subfolders, like:
gs://project-name-big-query-analytics_propertyId/events_/events_YYYYMMDD

and we need a more efficient way to get it back creating automatically the tables.
How can we do that in a better way?
I tried some python codes. Chat GPT gave this code, but I don't know how can I use it, like with how functionality in GCP?
import os

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage
def load_data_to_bigquery(event, context):
# Configurações
project_id = "app-xxxx"
dataset_id = "analytics_xxxx"
bucket_name = "app-xxx-big-query-analytics_xxxx"
folder_prefix = "/events_/events_*”
# Inicializa os clientes do BigQuery e Cloud Storage
bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)
storage_client = storage.Client(project=project_id)

# Lista todos os arquivos no bucket com o prefixo da pasta
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=folder_prefix)

for blob in blobs:
    # Obtém o nome da tabela (removendo o prefixo da pasta e a extensão do arquivo)
    table_name = os.path.splitext(blob.name[len(folder_prefix):])[0]

    # Cria a tabela no BigQuery se ela não existir
    table_ref = bq_client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_name)
    table = bigquery.Table(table_ref)
    table.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("coluna1", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("coluna2", "INTEGER"),
        # Adicione mais colunas conforme necessário
    ]
    bq_client.create_table(table, exists_ok=True)

    # Carrega os dados do arquivo no Cloud Storage para a tabela no BigQuery
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
    job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND

    uri = f"gs://{bucket_name}/{blob.name}"
    load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_uri(uri, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
    load_job.result()  # Aguarda a conclusão do job

    print(f"Dados carregados para a tabela {table_name}.")

if name == "main":
load_data_to_bigquery(None, None)  # Para testar localmente

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Chat GPT gave me a python code. but how can I use it?

Would setting up BigQuery tables to access the cloud storage bucket using external tables be suitable for your use case?

Hi, @PaddyAlton yes would work, but the main point is how can we automatize this?

I thought you were automatically putting files into a GCS bucket? If you use external tables you should be able to query anything in that bucket from BigQuery.
